# Как правильно генерировать html в зависимости от наличия аккаунта у пользователя?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Я на Django пишу веб-приложение для небольшого магазина и я наткнулся на задачу "Выдавать различный контент в зависимости от наличия аккаунта у пользователя", т.е банальное проверить куки и выдать соответствующий html. Возник вопрос: как правильнее всего реализовать? У меня есть две идеи:

1. Пропускать все запросы к view приложения, отвечающий за конкретный url, через отдельное приложение, которое будет проверять наличие аккаунта и передавать результат целевому приложению (можно через промежуточное приложение так же сразу генерировать header + footer для html)
2. В каждом приложении использовать из уже существующего приложении profiles методы для проверки наличия аккаунта
3. Ваш вариант

Дополнительный вопрос: я не особо понимаю можно ли в рамках "правильного" осуществлять взаимодействие приложений (использование методов друг друга и изменение моделей друг друга) или они должны жить не зная друг о друге? И как в общем правильнее декомпозировать логику приложения в отдельные единицы приложений?

Comment: Если под наличием аккаунта подразумевается "Авторизирован ли юзер", то все будет зависеть от технологий которые вы используете, от вашей схемы аутентификации-авторизации.

Comment: @air2921 Да, имеется в виду "Авторизован ли пользователь. На данный момент я не пришел к тому, какую схему аутентификации-авторизации использовать. Стандартная модель auth в джанго кажется излишней, ибо никаких схем проверки прав не нужно, поскольку все ограничивается банальным "если пользователь авторизован, то разрешить ему сохранять свои данные для облегчения оформления (сохранение адреса в профиле и тд), так же разрешить ему отслеживать заказы". Склоняюсь к тому, что лучше изобрести свой мини-велосипед, но опять же непонятки в том, как правильнее с "архитектурной" точки зрения это сделать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришел к выводу, что для меня удобнее будет сделать данную функциональность с помощью middleware

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]